# Permission in index file of magento can not be changed

Tags: magento

The link of the site is http://petonlineboutique.com/. The error which is showing in browser that is 403 forbidden error."You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request".

By google search we came to know that this forbidden error shows at that time when there is no enough permission.

Later I have noticed permission in all the files and folders of magento folder can be changed and made to 777 but index file permission is showing 000 and can not be changed.

So to get rid of this forbidden error if I need to put permission in index file, I can't put.

So help me what should I do now and tell us the reason why forbidden error and I can't change permission from cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around this. The only solution is changing permissions of the file, you just need to find out [how to do it](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/file_permissions.htm). If it won't allow you to change permissions on the file, you need to contact your host.